# How to wrap JSON response in a parent object

Tags: java, json, spring-rest

The current response from my Spring REST service is as below :

```
[
    {
        "id": "5cc81d256aaed62f8e6462f4",
        "email": "exmaplefdd@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "id": "5cc81d386aaed62f8e6462f5",
        "email": "exmaplefdd@gmail.com"
    }
]
```

I want to wrap that in a json object as below :

```
 {  
 "elements":[
      {
        "id": "5cc81d256aaed62f8e6462f4",
        "email": "exmaplefdd@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "id": "5cc81d386aaed62f8e6462f5",
        "email": "exmaplefdd@gmail.com"
     }
  ]
}
```

The controller :

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = GET,produces = "application/xml")
   @ResponseBody
   public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getPartnersByDate(@RequestParam("type") String type, @RequestParam("id") String id) throws ParseException {

   List<User> usersList = userService.getUsersByType(type);
   return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(usersList, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

User model class :

```
@Document(collection = "user")
public class User {

 @Id
 private String id;
 private String email;
}
```

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make a new Object to serialize:

```
class ResponseWrapper {
    private List<User> elements;

    ResponseWrapper(List<User> elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }
}
```

Then return an instance of `ResponseWrapper` in your controller method:

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = GET,produces = "application/xml")
   @ResponseBody
   public ResponseEntity<ResponseWrapper> getPartnersByDate(@RequestParam("type") String type, @RequestParam("id") String id) throws ParseException {

   List<User> usersList = userService.getUsersByType(type);
   ResponseWrapper wrapper = new ResponseWrapper(usersList);
   return new ResponseEntity<ResponseWrapper>(wrapper, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But im getting following exception. 
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 406 null

Comment: @GeekySelene https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406 Are you making your request using the `Accept:application/json` header?  Your annotations on your `getPartnersByDate` says that this produces `application/xml`, but in your original question it looks like you want json.  Maybe change your `@RequestMapping` to have `produces = "application/json"`

Comment: i fixed it and now getting this error. 
status 406, Could not find acceptable representation

Comment: i could fixed by adding the getter method for the wrapper class. thanks